# how to use array in where clause codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, controller

i have a function for update password 
i used tutorial from yt and its no problem , but if i run in my program its have error like this

> Message: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

```
public function getcurpasswd($id){
    $query = $this->db->where(['id'=>$id])->get('login');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->row();
    }
}
```

in this where clause is the problem ? what the solution ? thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace the following line:

```
$query = $this->db->where(['id'=>$id])->get('login');
```

by:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('login', array('id' => $id));
```